# JSDocs: Function returns function -> How to declare the returned function properly

Tags: javascript, function, types, typedef, jsdoc

I am trying to find out how to properly declare a returned function in JSDocs. This is my current code.

```
/**
 * An assertation function.
 * @typedef {Function} Assertation
 * @param {boolean} condition - Condition of assertation
 * @param {string} source - Source of the error
 * @param {Object|string} msg - Message to show
 * @param {string} [method] - Method on which errorHandler was invoked
 */

/**
 * Creates an assertion by calling console[type].
 * @param {string} [type=info] - Type of assertation
 * @returns {Assertation}
 */
const createAssertation = (type = 'info') => (condition, source, msg, method) => {
  if (condition && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console[type](createMessage(source, msg, method), msg);
  }
};
```

Comment: You could replace `{Assertation}` with `{(condition: boolean, source: string, msg : {}|string, method?: string) => void}`. Though you won' have the comments

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error? What error? Also your @typedef lacks a declaration following your jsdoc. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#typedef-type